# Restrict the valid values in one cell, based on the value in another cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to prevent a date being entered into a cell if the date precedes the date in another cell.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent entering a date in B2 that precedes the date in A2, apply the following Data Validation rule to B2:

Custom Formula  `= B2>=A2`

In the options, select "reject input on invalid data".