# Can Google Sheets use date data validation to make one column greater than another?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like my target completion column to have a date that is greater than my start column. Excel supports a date validation option but I do not see this in Google Sheets.

Is it there and I just don't know how to use it?

I saw this question: [Restrict the valid values in one cell, based on the value in another cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80101/restrict-the-valid-values-in-one-cell-based-on-the-value-in-another-cells/80112#80112?newreg=6e4831fa11a14f8191944b6fd52baafa)
but I can't see how to get it to apply to the same row in the other column.  Obviously I don't want a new rule on each cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, Google Sheets can.

## Instructions

1. Optional. Select the range to apply the data validation
2. Right click on the selected range or click on Data > Validation...
3. Optional. Write/edit the range to apply the data validation
4. Click on Criteria and select Date
   [image: Data Validation criteria dropdown options]
5. Set the rule options including a formula using the top left cell reference, i.e. `=A1`

[image: Data Validation date rule after cell value]

6. Click on the Save button.

Comment: This is good to know but I don't think it solves my problem.  I would like to require each cell in column B be after the date in the cell in the same row in column A.  That is, B2 must be after A2, B3 must be after A3, etc.  Is this possible?

Comment: That is exactly what the above instructions do. Please follow the instructions, just replace Sheet1!B1 by Sheet1!B:B or something similar. If the above instructions don't work for you create a demo spreadsheet to show what do you tried, share it with anyone with the link and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each cell in column B be after the date in the cell in the same row in column A. That is, B2 must be after A2, B3 must be after A3, etc., then do this:

In the criteria raw of the Data Validation window above, replace `=A1` with `=A1:A` and `Sheet1!B1` with `Sheet1!B1:B`